# Как настроить subfolder для laravel проектов на 1 домене

Tags: linux, nginx, laravel, configuration

Как настроить subfolder для laravel проектов на 1 домене

Имею конфигурацию

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name my-domain.com;

        root /home/jashka/sites/example/public;
        index index.php;

        error_log /home/jashka/sites/GlobalAppError.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ^~ /test-api {
                alias /home/jashka/sites/TestWebServiceAPI/public;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @testapi;

                location ~ \.php {
                        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }

        location @testapi {   
                rewrite /test-api/(.*)$ /test-api/index.php?$1 last;
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Не работает my-domain.com/test-api
точнее пустой экран
Такой код ответа

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 16:51:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: убедитесь, что при таком запросе происходит интерпретация именно `/home/jashka/sites/TestWebServiceAPI/public/index.php`

Comment: в заголовках явно нету показа про PHP, да и я правил файл /home/jashka/sites/TestWebServiceAPI/public/index.php что бы узнать выполняется ли он, и как оказалось, не происходит запроса

Comment: так тестируйте дальше. закомментируйте всю секцию `location ^~ /test-api`, проверьте, что получается, затем раскомментируйте, но закомментируйте внутри неё секцию `location ~ \.php`, т.д. и т.п. // так и поймёте, что именно у вас происходит.